# Git push fails with remote Permission denied

Tags: git, github

I am trying to push local change to my remote repository, but it is fails with 403 - Permission denied.

```
remote: Permission to rmanivannan/speedometer-jquery-plugin.git denied to mcttvni.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/rmanivannan/
speedometer-jquery-plugin.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Comment: https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/version-control-systems1/403-forbidden-error-message-when-you-try-to-push-to-a-github-repository

Comment: Thanks @channasmcs, shared URL is helpful, it worked after setting remote url (`git remote set-url origin "https://github-username@github.com/github-username/github-repository-name.git"
`)

Comment: Dude this helped me a lot... Thank you

Comment: Perhaps a related question from an hour ago:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68191392/password-authentication-is-temporarily-disabled-as-part-of-a-brownout-please-us

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to use git in ssh way, instead of account passwords .

> If you use a username and password to authenticate Git operations today, you should make the following changes to avoid disruption in the future:

> Follow the instructions to generate a personal access token for command-line use

> Update your Git configuration to securely store your personal access token (optional, but highly recommended)

from [github blog](https://github.blog/2020-07-30-token-authentication-requirements-for-api-and-git-operations/)

---

If you use ssh, remember to tick this

[image: 8888]

Answer (score 0):

found this answer helpful for me control panel > user accounts > credential manager > Windows credentials > Generic credentials by [Walid El Jaimi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58657029/remote-permission-to-denied-to)

Next, remove the Github keys. :)