# remote: Permission to ... denied to

Tags: git, push

When I do a `git push` I get this error:

```
$ git push -vv
Pushing to https://github.com/...
remote: Permission to ... denied to foobar.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/...': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

What I notice is that `foobar` user is not my user:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/... (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/... (push)
```

My configured github user is someone else:

```
$ git config github.user
ThisIsMe

$ git config --local github.user
```

Also that git module where I am have no reference to `foobar` in `.git/modules/ext/config`

Any clues?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permission denied error on Github Push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17857283/permission-denied-error-on-github-push)

Comment: I don't think you can push to https, try forking via the ssh URL and try again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you are  using Windows go to :

control panel > user accounts > credential manager > Windows credentials > Generic credentials

Next remove the Github keys. :)