# Github isn't aloowing me to login with username and password

Tags: github

Github isn't allowing me to login with username and password: showing follow error. Any immediate help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Password authentication is temporarily disabled as part of a brownout. Please use a personal access token instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68191392/password-authentication-is-temporarily-disabled-as-part-of-a-brownout-please-us)

Answer (score 0):

First of all generate SSH key from git account from here. [**Generate Token**](https://github.com/settings/tokens)  then follow below process.

Please run below commands

```
git remote remove origin

git credential-manager uninstall --force

git init

git remote add origin https://github.com/username/repo.git

git pull
```

It should be working for you after this. it is tested.