# how to replace my old password with my Personal access token to clone, pull, and push a repo?

Tags: git, github

I'm using multiple computers (Mac, Linux, and windows) so today I get surprised with the new way of pushing, pulling, or cloning a repo from GitHub.

when I'm trying to push my project I keep getting this error:

```
remote: Password authentication is temporarily disabled as part of a brownout. Please use a personal access token instead.
remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-07-30-token-authentication-requirements-for-api-and-git-operations/ for more information.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/barimehdi77/Philosophers.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

after multiple searches, I found this article [Creating a personal access token](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token), I created the token but the problem is how can I change the oldest password from my computers (I'm cloning, pushing and pulling form a public repo so I don't need to set my password every time).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Password authentication is temporarily disabled as part of a brownout. Please use a personal access token instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68191392/password-authentication-is-temporarily-disabled-as-part-of-a-brownout-please-us)

Comment: yes, but just for macOS, I still can't change it on Windows and Linux

Answer (score 1):

That link was for a specific thread. I'm just pasting it here for you. Try these steps

Password authentication is disabled by GitHub and not supported anymore. Create and use a Personal Access Token instead of a password.

**Steps to follow:**

Remove GitHub stored credentials from the "Credential Manager" on Windows

Generate access-token from Github Settings->Developer Settings->Personal access tokens->Generate new token

Save the token - As it will be available there for once only

Run command git fetch (or git push, if fetching doesn't require permissions)

on Windows, you must run this from Powershell, not Command Prompt. Command Prompt consistently fails with the remote: Password authentication is temporarily disabled message, despite identical inputs.

It will ask for your user name and password.

If it does not ask you for your username and password, you must change your git remote url to contain your username: https://USERNAME@github.com/repo-owner/repo-name.git (see approach 2 for instructions on changing remote url)

Put the access-token instead of the password when it asks for a password. (you will have to enter it twice)

**OR Second Approach:**

Generate access-token from Github Settings->Developer Settings->Personal access tokens->Generate new token

Update URL for origin locally: git remote set-url origin https://@<git_url>.git

Pull once: git pull https://@<git_url>.git

Comment: `git remote set-url origin https://@<git_url>.git`: I have to replace @ with my username?

Comment: for SSH:  git remote set-url origin git@github.com:<username>/<repo>.git                              

for HTTPS:  git remote set-url origin https://github.com/username/repo.git